# EXCEL AUTOMATION IN .NET ( COM Error )

Tags: .net, office-automation

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
```

i don't have ms-office in my system. I added the reference 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll' in my .net project(C#  code behind). i get the above error FROM the BELOW line

```
Application excel = new Application();
```

when i have ms-office installed it works fine. i should work it out without installing ms-office. only by adding dll. help needed. Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to create or edit Excel Files, I recommend using the new Open XML SDK from Microsoft. Works better and is easier than Excel Interop.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/excel/archive/2008/11/25/using-the-open-xml-sdk-to-work-with-excel-files.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem: "i should work it out without installing ms-office"

You cannot start Excel if not Excel is not installed (duh). What are you trying to do?

Comment: The dll is only an interop assembly that works as a proxy between Excel and .NET. It does not include excel itself. Use Open XML SDK to read or write Excel (xlsx) files without having Excel installed.